# Python refresh data in excel with external connection through add in doesnt work

Tags: win32com, python-3.8

I am using the following code to refresh data in excel file which uses external add in for receiving data.

```
import sys, os, pandas as pd, numpy as np, time, win32com.client
import win32com.client as w3c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    your_file_path = r'C:\Book11.xlsx'
    for ii in np.arange(1, 10):
        xlapp = w3c.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        xlapp.Visible = 0
        xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(your_file_path, False, True, None)
        books = w3c.Dispatch(xlwb)

        xlwb.RefreshAll()  # Runs with no errors, but doesn't refresh
        xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlwb.Save()
        xlapp.Quit()

        df = pd.read_excel(your_file_path)  # updates should be applied
        print(df)
        time.sleep(20)

# Another version of code that I tried is following:
# xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
# xlapp.Visible = True
# wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(your_file_path)
# wb.RefreshAll()
# xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
# xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
# wb.Save()
# xlapp.Quit()
```

However, the file doesn't refresh. In fact it looks like the following:

[image]

On the other hand if I just open the file on desktop using mouse clicks, I see the data as expected.

[image]

Comment: RefreshAll according to the docs does not have parentheses. have you tried without them? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.refreshall

Comment: Yes just tried that but file still doesn't refresh.

Comment: 1) Are you running this as a macro?

Comment: No the code is a python script not excel macro.

Comment: Can you check the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you running this as a macro?
2. Is refresh in bg property is false for all connections?

Things to try:

a)
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll instead of wbRefresh.RefreshAll

b)
Unchecking "enable background refresh" (uncheck to disable the background refresh)

Comment: No this doesnt work. I need a code which can be replicated so that I can accept you answer and award the bounty.